# How to link pharmacies table with medicine table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this two MySQL tables.

Pharmacies table

[image: Pharmacies]

Medicine table

[image: Medicine]

How can i link this two tables So that each pharmacy have their own medicine stock(One medicine can be in multiple pharmacies).

Comment: just create a third table with two columns: pharmacy_id and medicine_id. Then it's a matter of join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a third table to join the two, something looking like this.

```
------------------------
| pID | mID | Quantity |
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make Pname or pID as a primary key and mID as the foreign key , this will allow each pharmacy to have its own stock of medicines